# Почему после реквайр таска зарегистрируем таск (gulp)?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Есть таск галпа вынесенный на отдельный файл

```
module.exports = function() {
$.gulp.task('sass', function() {
return $.gulp.src('*.scss')
.pipe($.gulp.dest('./build/'))
})
};
```

в gulpfile.js таск зареквайриться и потом зарегистрируется

```
global.$ = {
gulp: require('gulp'),
gp: require('gulp-load-plugins')()
};
require('./gulp/tasks/sass.js')();
$.gulp.task('sass');
```

почему таск в gulpfile.js снова зарегистрируется, а ведь в модуле тоже зарегистрируется.

Comment: что зарегистрируется?